# How to display nested @component in a ngFor loop with angular4?

Tags: angular, nested, components, ngfor

I've just started learning Angular4 and I am facing an issue I cannot explain.

I'm now trying to build two components :

My main component is **chatComponent** it is supposed to display a list of child components **msgComponent**.

For this I defined an array of message **msgArray**  in app.chatComponent and iterate over the messages through à ***ngFor directive**. For each messages I want to display a child component app.messageComponent.

So far, everything works well except **the first message in msgArray is never displayed**...

Why?

> Here is my **app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgForOf  } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel, FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';


import { ChatComponent } from './app.chatComponent';
import { MsgComponent } from './app.msgComponent';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule 
  ],
  declarations: [
    ChatComponent,
    MsgComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ChatComponent, MsgComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> Here is my main component :
>   **app.chatComponent.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MsgComponent } from './app.msgComponent';
import { Msg } from './app.msgModel';

var msgArray: Msg[] = [
  { id: '11', content: 'msg0' },
  { id: '11', content: 'msg1' },
  { id: '12', content: 'msg2' },
  { id: '13', content: 'msg3' },
  { id: '14', content: 'msg4' },
  { id: '15', content: 'msg5' },
  { id: '16', content: 'msg6' },
  { id: '17', content: 'msg7' },
  { id: '18', content: 'msg8' },
  { id: '19', content: 'msg9' },
  { id: '20', content: 'msg10' }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'chat-component',
  templateUrl: './app.chatComponent.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.chatComponent.css']
})
export class ChatComponent {
    messages: Msg[] = msgArray;
    msg: Msg = new Msg();
}
```

> **app.chatComponent.html**

```
<div>
    <ul class="messages">
        <msg-component *ngFor="let msg of messages" [msg]="msg.content"></msg-component>
    </ul>
</div>
<input [(ngModel)]="msg.content">
```

> Here is my child component : **app.msgComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Msg } from './app.msgModel';
@Component({
  selector: 'msg-component',
  templateUrl: './app.msgComponent.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.msgComponent.css']
})
export class MsgComponent {
    @Input() msg: Msg;
}
```

> **app.msgComponent.html**

```
<li>{{msg}}</li>
```

[See demo on plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mttSZ6sanD8k7GCgwUSx?p=preview)

Comment: there is a typo in app.chatComponent.html. Should be "let msg of messages"

Comment: @rjustin You're right sorry I corrected it was a copy/past mistake. But it doesn't explain my problem :)

Comment: Can you make a plunker with what you have and get it to run?

Comment: @rjustin here is the demo on plunker, as you can see my first message's content is not displayed. ( actually the value of the first message is null ) 

https://plnkr.co/edit/mttSZ6sanD8k7GCgwUSx?p=preview

Comment: This a very odd problem. I have looked at this for 20 minutes now and am baffled. It has something to do with the @Input msg being null. if you set that it will show in the first item. This is not expected behavior. Ill keep fiddling with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem is that you are bootstrapping the msg component breaking the first render loop **like so**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgForOf  } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel, FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';


import { ChatComponent } from './app.chatComponent';
import { MsgComponent } from './app.msgComponent';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule 
  ],
  declarations: [
    ChatComponent,
    MsgComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ChatComponent, MsgComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Instead try this:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgForOf  } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

import { ChatComponent } from 'src/app.chatComponent';
import { MsgComponent } from 'src/app.msgComponent';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule 
  ],
  declarations: [
    ChatComponent,
    MsgComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ChatComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[here is a working simplified version.](https://plnkr.co/edit/oW9fKHhHVoz8yiKUQTvV?p=preview)

You dont need to bootstrap all you components, you just need to have them in declarations.

Comment: Tanks for this answer, it's working well. How would you explain quickly the role of this "bootstrap" directive ?

Comment: @jmchey If this answer worked for you please mark it as accepted to help others in the future.  Here is the link to docs about bootstrapping https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping

Comment: I'm doing it sorry, I'm new here :)